# Get data from response after url request in Flutter

Tags: flutter, oauth

I'm trying to implement OAuth 1.0 in Flutter.
OAuth 1.0 works as follows:[image: OAuth flow]
My app asks for a request token, which is provided by the service I want to authenticate to. Then the user is redirected to a page belonging to the service where it grants the authorization to access data to my app. Now I can ask for the access token which will be used to sign every future data request.

I'm using [this OAuth plugin](https://github.com/nbspou/dart-oauth1) for the OAuth procedure and [Url Launcher plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to perform requests, since the first plugin waits for pin data, while I'd like the user to enjoy full automated process.
I'm able to ask for the request token through the OAuth library, but the following code only launches the url, so I cannot retrieve data from the response.

```
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url, forceWebView: true, enableJavaScript: true);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
```

How can I get data after user interaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take a look into the [flutter_web_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth). I used this for OAuth login for Unsplash.

```
final url = Uri.https('unsplash.com', 'oauth/authorize', {
      'response_type': 'code',
      'client_id': client_id,
      'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
      'scope': scode,
    });

final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
        url: url
            .toString()
            .replaceAll("%2B", "+"),
        callbackUrlScheme: "foobar");
```

You need to replace '%2B' with + because the url generator replaces the + symbol with %2B.

```
final code = Uri.parse(result).queryParameters['code'];
```

You will get the code which you need to pass it to the post request to get the token.

Sure there are other OAuth provider for flutter but this I have used in one of my application and its tested also.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't perform the token request as first step; could you suggest me how to do it?

Comment: can you share the steps you took for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm accepting the answer by pradyot1996, but I give some explanation.

The hint given above made me go deeper into OAuth 1.0a and the [plugin](https://github.com/nbspou/dart-oauth1). The step I was missing was that I could add a redirect uri, which is then called in place of the web page showing the authentication code. This is the best way to obtain the verifier code the server returns.

Moreover, [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin), possibly like the one suggested by pradyot1996, permits to open a webpage inside of the app, without the need to ask the system to open a browser and start a server to listen to the answer. Though this is a bad practice, as stated [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-8.12), I'm offering this option in my app informing the user. Maybe I'll add both the options, to be crystal clear.